# Java - Arquivo XML - Arquivo final vazio

Tags: java, xml, arquivo, io

Tenho um webservice Java que é acionado para realizar integrações via troca de arquivos XML com um ERP, ele funcionou perfeitamente desde o dia que desenvolvi ele. Ontem pela manhã, ele passou a gerar arquivos XML vazios sem nenhuma alteração de seu código-fonte. Qualquer requisição realizada a ele gera arquivos vazios, impossibilitando a interface entre as plataformas.
Analisando o log do servidor, o seguinte erro aparece:

```
ERROR:  'Input/output error'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Input/output error
java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:743)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:345)
        at br.com.allis.XMLFiles.RequisicaoReembolso.createXML(RequisicaoReembolso.java:252)
        at br.com.allis.XMLFiles.XMLParser.generateXML(XMLParser.java:63)
        at br.com.allis.ws.AllisWS.generateXML(AllisWS.java:1126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:121)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:646)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1576)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Input/output error
java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.flushWriter(ToStream.java:304)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLStream.endDocument(ToXMLStream.java:213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.endDocument(ToUnknownStream.java:829)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:139)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:687)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:731)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.flushBuffer(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:450)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.flush(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:469)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.flushWriter(ToStream.java:285)
        ... 44 more
```

Já tentei dar deploy no webservice novamente, já que não houve alteração de seu código mas sem sucesso.
Quando executo a aplicação localmente, funciona...

```java
public ReturnMsg createXML(String paramsJson) {
        ReturnMsg retorno = new ReturnMsg();
        try {
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element root = doc.createElement("DEMANDA");
            doc.appendChild(root);
            JsonObject requisicao = parser.parse(paramsJson).getAsJsonObject();
            String numDemanda = requisicao.get("NUM_DEM").getAsString();
            int numRequisicao = Integer.parseInt(numDemanda);
            this.log.setNumeroDemanda(numRequisicao);
            String tpDemanda = requisicao.get("TIP_DEM").getAsString();
            String codEmpresa = requisicao.get("COD_EMP").getAsString();
            String cnpj = requisicao.get("CNPJ_FOR").getAsString();
            String cpf = requisicao.get("CPF_FOR").getAsString();
            String dtFaturamento = requisicao.get("DAT_FAT").getAsString();
            String textExp = requisicao.get("TEX_EXP").getAsString();
            String textCab = requisicao.get("TEX_CAB").getAsString();
            String destRecurso = requisicao.get("DEST_REC").getAsString();
            String motivoDespesa = requisicao.get("MOT_DESP").getAsString()
            int numDestRecurso = Integer.parseInt(destRecurso);
            int numMotivoDespesa = motivoDespesa != "" ? Integer.parseInt(motivoDespesa) : 0;

            Element src = doc.createElement("SRC");
            String txtSrc = "fluig";

            Element nDemanda = doc.createElement("NUM_DEM");
            Element tDemanda = doc.createElement("TIP_DEM");
            Element cEmpresa = doc.createElement("COD_EMP");
            Element cnpjF = doc.createElement("CNPJ_FOR");
            Element cpfF = doc.createElement("CPF_FOR");
            Element dtFat = doc.createElement("DAT_FAT");
            Element txtExp = doc.createElement("TEX_EXP");
            Element txtCab = doc.createElement("TEX_CAB");
            Element itens = doc.createElement("ITENS");

            src.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(txtSrc));
            nDemanda.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(numDemanda));
            tDemanda.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(tpDemanda));
            cEmpresa.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(codEmpresa));
            cnpjF.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(cnpj));
            cpfF.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(cpf));
            dtFat.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(dtFaturamento));
            txtExp.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(textExp));
            txtCab.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(textCab));

            root.appendChild(src);
            root.appendChild(nDemanda);
            root.appendChild(tDemanda);
            root.appendChild(cEmpresa);
            root.appendChild(cnpjF);
            root.appendChild(cpfF);
            root.appendChild(dtFat);
            root.appendChild(txtExp);
            root.appendChild(txtCab);

            JsonArray itensJson = requisicao.get("ITENS").getAsJsonArray();

            for (int i = 0, size = itensJson.size(); i < size; i++) {
                JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) itensJson.get(i);

                Element item = doc.createElement("ITEM");
                Element tipDes = doc.createElement("TIP_DES");
                Element valLin = doc.createElement("VAL_LIN");
                Element cCusto = doc.createElement("C_CUSTO");
                Element ePep = doc.createElement("E_PEP");

                if( i == 0 ){
                    String cenCusto = !obj.get("C_CUSTO").getAsString().isEmpty() ? obj.get("C_CUSTO").getAsString() : obj.get("E_PEP").getAsString();
                }
                item.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("ITEM").getAsString()));
                tipDes.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("TIP_DES").getAsString()));               valLin.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("VAL_LIN").getAsString()));           cCusto.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("C_CUSTO").getAsString()));               ePep.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("E_PEP").getAsString()));


                item.appendChild(tipDes);
                item.appendChild(valLin);
                item.appendChild(cCusto);
                item.appendChild(ePep);

                itens.appendChild(item);
            }


            root.appendChild(itens);

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,"yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"xml");

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(this.getNomeArq()));
            transformer.transform(source, result); // linha do erro

            retorno.setSuccess(true);
            retorno.setMotivo("Sucesso");
            retorno.setObs("Arquivo gerado com sucesso");
            retorno.setTipoRetorno("ok");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
            retorno.setSuccess(false);
            retorno.setMotivo("Erro");
            retorno.setObs("Erro criação do arquivo XML");
            retorno.setTipoRetorno("exc");
        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            retorno.setSuccess(false);
            retorno.setMotivo("Erro");
            retorno.setObs("Erro criação do arquivo XML");
            retorno.setTipoRetorno("exc");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            retorno.setSuccess(false);
            retorno.setMotivo("Erro");
            retorno.setObs("Erro criação do arquivo XML");
            retorno.setTipoRetorno("exc");
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Arquivo de saída esperado

```xml
<DEMANDA>
    <SRC></SRC>
    <NUM_DEM></NUM_DEM>
    <TIP_DEM></TIP_DEM>
    <COD_EMP></COD_EMP>
    <CNPJ_FOR></CNPJ_FOR>
    <CPF_FOR></CPF_FOR>
    <DAT_FAT></DAT_FAT>
    <TEX_EXP></TEX_EXP>
    <TEX_CAB></TEX_CAB>
    <ITENS>
        <ITEM>
            <TIP_DES></TIP_DES>
            <VAL_LIN></VAL_LIN>
            <C_CUSTO></C_CUSTO>
            <E_PEP></E_PEP>
        </ITEM>
    </ITENS>
</DEMANDA>
```

Algum norte a ser seguido para solucionar esse caso?

Comment: Não houve atualização de nenhuma lib? Há espaço em disco para gravar estes xmls?

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante, sim tem espaço em disco, bastante até... Já limpei também a pasta temporária do servidor, sem nenhum sucesso

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante também não houve mudança de lib, a aplicação não teve republicação até o momento que o erro foi notado, se não me falha a memória, a última atualização aconteceu em dezembro ou janeiro

Comment: Não houve alguma alteração de permissão essas coisas? Se o código não foi alterado, é interessante investigar o ambiente..